# How to set [$expand PageSize] for OData in ASP.NET WEB API?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, odata

I use the server-side page like this:

```
[Queryable(PageSize = 20)]
public IQueryable<T> Get()
{
    return Repository<T>.GetAll();
}
```

then,I get items as GET **http://domain.com/oData/EntityA?$expand=EntityB**.
As I expected I got 10 "EntityA",but the navigation properties "EntityB" always only 10,too.

I google it,but nothing helped.
At [$select and $expand support](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=%24select%20and%20%24expand%20support) has some tip,but not solution:

---

PageSize for expanded feeds.

How can one specify page size for expanded feeds? WCF DS has a per entity-set configuration knob for page size. Should we follow their model?

---

**So,how can I get all of EntityB though $expand,is need some config?**

*version:*

*Mvc 5.0.0-beta2*

*WebApi 5.0.0-beta2*

*WebApi.OData 5.0.0-rc1-130807*

*Data.OData 5.6.0-rc1*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This feature is not implemented yet. We only have support for basic paging where the page size of the expanded feed is the same as the page size of the top feed. [This](https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/workitem/1016) is the issue on codeplex tracking it. Please vote for it to bump up its priority if it is important for you.

Comment: Thanks,I voted it.
And has some way to solve it before you implemented?
Now,we have to query multiple times for every expanded feeds,it's looks stupid.